# Cannot get iframe to appear on static HTML page after knitting through Rmarkdown

Tags: iframe, markdown, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I have searched for solutions, but cannot seem to get an iframe to appear on my static HTML blog page. All I am doing is pasting the iframe as given from the source into the body of the Rmarkdown document inside RStudio IDE. After serving my site using the blogdown package, the page renders but without the iframe content, the place on the page being blank.

This is the iframe content in question:

`<iframe width="600" height="600" src="https://earthengine.google.com/iframes/timelapse_player_embed.html#v=41.19349,-112.3765,7.414,latLng&amp;t=0.33" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Other iframe content such as a YouTube video will render on the HTML page without any issue. However, the place on the page where the map should appear is just blank.

Comment: Could you provide the site (and github repo) ? By the way, you could hit `F12` in chrome to get in developer tools, and see if there are errors under `Console` tab

Comment: When I check under F12>Console, I see the following:
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT`

Site is: [https://gradcylinder.com/post/2017/05/timelapse/]

Comment: your page is perfectly fine on my browser, maybe it's a network issue.

Comment: Oh my freaking goodness!!! Stupid Chrome extension was preventing EarthEngine script from running on MY browser. Everything is fine now. Thank you, TC.

May I leave this issue here so that others may learn from my mistake.

Comment: I suggest that you write it as an answer and accept it, so that this question will not appear under the 'unanswered' tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When including iframe content in a markdown post that will be knitted and converted to an html page using `blogdown`, and when that iframe content does not appear on the html page, check that no privacy-oriented/script-blocking extensions are running in Chrome. For example, when Privacy Badger is enabled, site content will often be blocked from loading.